# Spark apply custom schema to a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a data in Parquet file and want to apply custom schema to it.

My initial data within Parquet is as below,

```
root
 |-- CUST_ID: decimal(9,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- INACTV_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- UPDT_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ACTV_DT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PMT_AMT: decimal(9,4) (nullable = true)
 |-- CMT_ID: decimal(38,14) (nullable = true)
```

My custom schema is below,

```
root
 |-- CUST_ID: decimal(38,0) (nullable = false)
 |-- INACTV_DT: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- UPDT_DT: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- ACTV_DT: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- PMT_AMT: decimal(19,4) (nullable = true)
 |-- CMT_ID: decimal(38,14) (nullable = false)
```

Below is my code to apply new data-frame to it

```
val customSchema = getOracleDBSchema(sparkSession, QUERY).schema
val DF_frmOldParkquet = sqlContext_par.read.parquet("src/main/resources/data_0_0_0.parquet")
val rows: RDD[Row] = DF_frmOldParkquet.rdd
val newDataFrame = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, tblSchema)
newDataFrame.printSchema()
newDataFrame.show()
```

I am getting below error, when I perform this operation.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of timestamp
staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$, DecimalType(38,0), fromDecimal, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, CUST_ID), DecimalType(38,0)), true) AS CUST_ID#27
```

Comment: Are you able to find out solution to this problem?? Please post if you have any solution to this.

Answer (score 8):

There are two main applications of schema in Spark SQL

- `schema` argument passed to [`schema` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@schema(schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) of the [`DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) which is used to transform data in some formats (primarily plain text files). In this case schema can be used to automatically cast input records.
- `schema` argument passed to `createDataFrame` (variants which take `RDD` or `List` of `Rows`) of the [`SparkSession`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession). In this case schema has to conform to the data, and is not used for casting.

None of the above is applicable in your case:

- Input is strongly typed, therefore `schema`, if present, is ignored by the reader.
- Schema doesn't match the data, therefore it cannot be used to `createDataFrame`.

In this scenario you should `cast` each column to the desired type. Assuming the types are compatible, something like this should work

```
val newDataFrame = df.schema.fields.foldLeft(df){ 
  (df, s) => df.withColumn(s.name, df(s.name).cast(s.dataType))     
}
```

Depending on the format of the data this might be sufficient or not. For example if fields that should be transformed to timestamps don't use standard formatting, casting won't work, and you'll have to use Spark datetime processing utilities.